# Load text file into an array, the result is unexpected

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an iOS Swift homework, in which I have to load a text file into an array of words, and then print out the occurrence of each word. At the first step, I have my code like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("news", ofType: "txt")
        var possibleContent = String.stringWithContentsOfFile(path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)

        if let content = possibleContent {
            var array = content.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

            for text in array {
                println(content)
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

For example, the string is "1 2 3 4 5", I expected it would print out exact "1 2 3 4 5", but my console output was the duplication of "1 2 3 4 5", exact 4 times repeated that string, equal to the number of spaces. Can you point out where my bug is, and how can I count the words occurrence by the simplest way? Thank you.

Comment: Replace `println(content)` by `println(text)`

Comment: It works! So simple, thanks. And about the word occurrence, can you suggest a solution? I found some class named NSCountedSet but I can't apply it to my Swift code.

Comment: NS(Mutable)CountedSet is a good solution.